# How do I use the "IF" function on excel to sort datas when provided cell references?

Tags: excel

I need to use the "IF" function on excel to sort these data according to their corresponding codes (the ones I've circled in red), but as you can see on the table at the bottom, there are only the first two letters of the codes of the ones at the top table. (e.g., CF, CD, DP, DF), while on the table above, there are numbers that follow those letters (e.g., CF123, DF123). How do i separate them so that i can sort the data properly using the "IF" function on excel?

[image]

Comment: Add a helper column to put next to the CODE? `=LEFT(B2,2)`? (if `CF123` is in `B2`, adjust otherwise)

Comment: @BruceWayne you're back! Long time no see ^_^